# How to get Span value on back end C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I created a client portal in asp.net, in which client give me feedback for that a ready paragraph is given and empty space is given for fill up using span
asp.net code :

```
<p style="font-size: larger; color:white; line-height:15pt; font-family:Arial;">
Hi my name is
    <strong>
        <span contenteditable="true" runat="server" id="Sname" class="text" data-placeholder="T.B. Giri" data-focused-advice="_____">
        </span>
    </strong>
</p>
```

i want this span tag value which may change by client side on button click...
thank you

Comment: So, when a button is clicked, you want the span to change?

Comment: Well post your data with ajax, or download it with your form. I don't know how you implemented your site structure, but with Jquery you can get the value of you <p>, $("#Sname).val()

Comment: You either need to make the span `runat` to be server side, but ASP.NET wants you to work within the form, so best solution would probably be a client side method to sync the span value to a hidden input or to directly post the data to your server side code.

Comment: @Jamie Rees: I dont want to change its value, all i need to get span value on button click

Comment: @Kram Can give me idea about how to use ajax for that as i am not much good in ajax

Comment: @ Jason W : Can you give me Some Example

Comment: Try to implement this code: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/. If you have any further question ask.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have made it `runat=server` you can access it on serverside. The span is a `HtmlGenericControl` at serverside:

```
string value = Sname.InnerText;
```

I would use a `Label` instead which is rendered as `span`.

However, in this case i'm fairly sure that you don't get the value that was changed at clientside since it is re-created from `ViewState` at serverside. If that's true you need to use a different approach like using a `HiddenField` and set it's `value` on clientside.

Comment: @TGiri: then go with the suggested  HiddenField approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use Hidden field to hold actual value and get the value from the hidden field, use span to display only